# Elements in table not being read because of uncaught error

Tags: javascript

I'm so frustrated with a project I working on in which if there are duplicate elements in a table I want to hide them. I find the duplicates without a problem. The issues starts when I try to hide the duplicates. I'm using vanilla JavaScript without any frame works or libraries. I get this error that is really hard to decipher.

> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'e' of undefined

`e` is first duplicate element in the table

I don't have any hard coded data in my HTML - it's all JavaScript. I have never done a display none this way before so I thought I would reach out for some help. My code is below.

Appreciating Your Help In Advance.

```js
var data = [
  ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['a', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
  ['a', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
  ['a', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
  ['b', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['b', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
  ['c', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
  ['d', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78],
  ['d', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['d', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
  ['e', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
  ['e', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
  ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['e', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
  ['e', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
  ['e', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78]
];





//Create a HTML Table element.
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("tableRow");


//Get the count of columns.
var columnCount = data[0].length;


//Add the data rows.

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
    //Searching for duplicates            
    var num = data[i][0];
    for (var otherRow = i + 1; otherRow < data.length; otherRow++) {
      var dup = data[otherRow][0];
      console.log("What is the dup" + dup);
      if (num === dup) {
        console.log("duplicate");
        elems.data[dup].style.display = "none";

      }
    }


    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = data[i][j];
    cell.innerHtml = myZero;

  }
}


var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
dvTable.innerHTML = "";
dvTable.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Hi     is there any other way to hide these elements using JavaScript or a way around this that you can think of?

Comment: I do have an html document with those tags there but there is no data, all data in table is coming from the array which I populated into a table.

Comment: Variables `data` and `elems` are not related in any way in your code. The value of `elems` is a `NodeList` of DOM elements which doesn't have a property named `data`, and therefore you have an error when you try to use property `e` (value of `dup`) in a non-existing object (`elems.data`)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the de-duplication and actually creating the elements from your data. Using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) you can remove all duplicates so you don't have to worry about that when you do the inserting.

```js
var data = [
  ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['a', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
  ['a', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
  ['a', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
  ['b', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['b', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
  ['c', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
  ['d', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78],
  ['d', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['d', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
  ['e', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
  ['e', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
  ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['e', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
  ['e', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
  ['e', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78]
];


var alreadyFound = [];

data = data.filter(function(item, pos, arr) {
  var key = item[0];
  // If we have already found this character, then skip.
  if (alreadyFound.indexOf(key) > -1) return false;
  // Otherwise, add this char to alreadyFound and include the item.
  alreadyFound.push(key);
  return true;
});


//Create a HTML Table element.
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("tableRow");


//Get the count of columns.
var columnCount = data[0].length;


//Add the data rows.

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = data[i][j];
  }
}


var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
dvTable.innerHTML = "";
dvTable.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="dvTable"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for trying but this won't work for what I'm trying to accomplish which is to check for duplicates on previous row not all duplicates in the table

Comment: Hi I tried the above logic for multiDimlUniq but its not working for me. Of course I modified the name of the array to mines.  I not sure I understand what the reduce is for.

Comment: @user2280852 "if there are duplicate elements in a table I want to hide them." -- I feel like I'm missing some context. Can you modify your original question to include exactly what you need? There is currently nothing there mentioning that you only want to dedupe specific rows and not all rows.

Comment: Sure, What I'm trying to accomplish is when displaying the first column if it is the same value as the previous row I do not want to display the value,

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I had things a bit out of order,  The key to figuring things out is not to spin your wheels, but just walk away.

Comment: I couldn't use the suggestions given because I was doing other things with the table such as finding the ones that had zeros than moving them to the end which I suppose I could have done. But what the purpose code does is remove duplicates when I want to remove based on previous/current and next. Which would give a much different result

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Red Mercury. you first need to remove duplicates in your array.
Red Mercury answer is perfectly valid but here is a dirty quick multi-dimensional array deduplication function I am using for such stuff.

```
var data = [
    ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['a', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['a', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
    ['a', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
    ['b', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['b', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['c', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
    ['d', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78],
    ['d', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['d', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['e', 6, 7, 8, 9, 232],
    ['e', 54, 11235, 345, 5, 6],
    ['e', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['e', 54312, 235, 5, 15, 4],
    ['e', 62, 15, 754, 93, 323],
    ['e', 27, 11235, 425, 18, 78]
];

function multiDimlUniq(arr) {
    var uniques = [];
    var founds = {};
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        var s = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
        if (founds[s]) {
            continue;
        }
        uniques.push(arr[i]);
        founds[s] = true;
    }
    return uniques;
}

var reduced = multiDimlUniq(data)
```